# Firefox Start issue when another instance is already open

Tags: firefox, browser, grid

I have firefox 25 installed on my windows7 64 bit system. I needed firefox 21 for some testing. When I start firefox.exe from firefox21 directory, when another instance of firefox25 is already open, it spawns a browser, but from help->about firefox, I got that it was a 25 version. But when I start the firefox.exe file without having already open instance of 25 it starts a 21 version browser.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a `Virtual Machine` for this purpose.

Other way is by using `Firefox Profiles`.

Here is the way to do so https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles